# useradd and user management in Plasma

Tags: debian, kde, useradd, plasma5

I added a user in the terminal

```
useradd -m -g <groupID> -u <userID> <username>
```

Now, going to the user management of KDE I tried to change the name of the account (NOT the user name), but it is not possible (error returned). Am I missing some additional changes except from `useradd`?

*My system: Debian 11, Kernel 5.14, KDE Plasma 5.20.5*

Comment: Here we go with the trickle again... it helps if you tell us what the error message is. FWIW, I can do it just fine on my opensuse system. If you are running it as the local user, you can only change your own account name. If you try and change someone else's, then you have to switch to root in some way.

Comment: I hava admin rights and the error is "An error occurred". Here you are.

Comment: Unix/Linux does not have the notion of `admin rights`. The last time I saw someone say that, they have changed their own uid to `0`. So, you will have to tell us the nature of that. There are also these things called logs that need trawling through.